# Woocommerce product rating only with stars

Tags: woocommerce, comments, rating, required-field

I am trying to make the woocommerce product rating only with stars. Therefore I need to remove the currently required fields name, email and comment.

I have accomplished to remove comment with this code

```
<?php
function rei_preprocess_comment($comment_data) {
    if ($comment_data['comment_content'] == '%dummy-text%') {
        $comment_data['comment_content'] = ''; // replace dummy text.
    }
    return $comment_data;
}
add_filter('preprocess_comment', 'rei_preprocess_comment');
function rei_wp_footer() {
    ?>
    <script>
    jQuery(function($){
        var comment = $('textarea#comment');
        comment.removeAttr('required'); // remove required attribute of textarea.
        $('#commentform').on('submit',function(){
            if (comment.val() == '') {
                comment.css('text-indent','-999px').val('%dummy-text%'); // change to dummy text.
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'rei_wp_footer' );
?>
```

However I am not being able to remove the required name and email field so unregistered user can enter the star product rating.

Please help

Comment: The code above is not working. When I try to add a second rating for a product I get the message "You have already said that"

Answer (score 0):

This is an option in Wordpress go to Settings > Discussion  and look for the required email and name setting. Remove the checkmark and save the settings page.

Comment: Thnx, but I need to modify the product reviews and not post reviews. The option in Settings > Discussion is only for post reviews.

Comment: You are right, it is working with change in settings.

Comment: The reason is that Woocomerce use post comments for there review system. Every Review is a comment with special attributes.